# Funcionalidad de For in, de javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tomando un curso de javascript. Pero me surge duda con un for in que se usa.
Ejemplo en el HTML se tiene varios divs con la class="rojo".
Y en javascript se hará que el backrground de esas  clases se pinte de rojo.

Con este codigo:

```
var divsRojos = document.getElementByClassName('claseDelDiv'); //toma todos los elementos que tengan la clase "claseDelDiv"
var nuevavariable; // <-- ¿para que?

for (nuevavariable in divsRojos){
    if(divsRojos[nuevavariable].className =='rojo'){

     divsRojos[nuevavariable].stylebackground = "red";
    }
```

Mi duda esta en:
¿para qué se declara esa variable "nuevavariable" y se usa en el " for (nuevavariable in divsRojos)" ?

Comment: Aqui tienes la respuesta a las dudas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in

Comment: Se declara porque la sintaxis del bucle [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in#Sintaxis) está definida para recibir una variable, sea esta declarada con anterioridad, como el ejemplo que muestras o pudiéndola declarar directamente dentro de la sentencia del bucle: `for(let variable in iterador){ ... }`. La diferencia radica que en la primera forma, la variable pertenece al ámbito donde vive el bucle, de la segunda forma la variable sólo es accesible dentro del bucle (porque fue declarada usando `let` en este caso). Saludos